# XMLHttpRequest не работает в асинхронном режиме. Status == 0

Tags: ajax, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Вот мой код, может я не правильно обрабатываю запрос но req.status == 0 постоянно

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest; 
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    var date = "test";
    var url = "qservice.php";
    if (q) {
        var dur = new Date(q.mint);

        var _userOffset = dur.getTimezoneOffset()*60000; 
        date = new Date(dur.valueOf()-60000-_userOffset);
        url+="?date="+date.toISOString();
    } else {
        url += "?date=test";
    }
    req.open('GET', url, true);

    req.onload = function () {

        if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
            q = (JSON.parse(req.responseText));
            f(q);
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
        }

    }

    req.send(null);
```

Comment: onreadystatechange вместо onload, где вы onload взяли ? и ставьте этот хэнлер **до** open

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

OnLoad пишется, onreadystate если меняется, то же самое все происходит, status == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй этот код. я там добавил пару комментов http://jsfiddle.net/yrsWy/

этот код 100% рабочий. у меня все работает

Comment: у меня и с onload работать начало я почти ничего не менял. Хм, теперь все работает, ну ладно.